# No module named 'requests' python3

Tags: python, request

I am working on a Python script that utilizes the 'requests' module to make HTTP requests. However, I am encountering an ImportError. Here are the details:

code:

```
  import requests

  url = 'https://example.com'
  response = requests.get(url)

  print(response.text)
```

I have checked that the 'requests' module is installed using pip install requests.
I've also confirmed that I'm using the correct virtual environment.

Comment: Verify that you are using the correct Python interpreter to run your script. If you're using `virtualenv`, the correct interpreter should be located within the virtual environment's bin directory. Also check for conflicting packages. Could you post how you set up the path of the virtual environment?

Comment: What does `python -m pip show requests` tell you?

Comment: It appears that you have two separate installations of python on your computer.  Please edit the question and include the output of these commands `which pip` and `pip show requests`, and also the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 0):

If you've confirmed that the 'requests' module is installed and you're using the correct virtual environment, it's possible that there might be an issue with the environment or the way you're running the script. Here are a few things you can check and try:

1. Activate Virtual Environment:
   Ensure that your virtual environment is activated before running the script. You should see the virtual environment's name in your terminal prompt. If it's not activated, you can activate it using:

source /path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/activate
Replace /path/to/your/virtualenv with the actual path to your virtual environment.

2. Install Requests in the Virtual Environment:
   Confirm that the 'requests' module is installed in your virtual environment. While the virtual environment is activated, run:

pip list

Check if 'requests' is listed in the output. If not, install it again using:

pip install requests

3. Check Python Version:
   Ensure that you are running the script with the correct version of Python associated with your virtual environment. You can check the Python version by running:

python --version
It should match the Python version for which the virtual environment was created.

4. Check Script Execution:
   Ensure that you are running your script with the correct Python executable within your virtual environment. Instead of just python script.py, use:

/path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/python script.py
Replace /path/to/your/virtualenv with the actual path to your virtual environment.

5. Check File Name Conflicts:
   Make sure that your script file doesn't have the same name as a module or package in the standard library or any other installed packages. This could cause conflicts.

Comment: Are you aware of [our policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?